# Claiming on registered international mail in Japan

Tags: japan, mail

I'm sending a lot of items back to the UK from Japan and paying about triple the standard cost to register my mail (kakitome; 書留). However, I've yet to find a portal where I can actually claim on undelivered mail. I'd like to know:

- how long has to pass before I can claim, and
- whether registered means it's tracked and traced just in Japan or in the recipient's country as well.

I have looked all over the English version of the Japan Post Office website to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried asking the desk clerk about these ? Typically I believe you'd file a claim with your national post first with the slip JP gives you, if they can't trace it then you would contact JP

Answer (score 1):

How about [this page?](https://trackings.post.japanpost.jp/services/srv/search/?locale=en)
It allows to track some packages, but I'm not sure if it is what you need specifically.